# Is there a pre-push type of hook for git that happens BEFORE git asks for credentials?

Tags: git

I have a git pre-push hook that runs unit tests. The issue is git connects to the remote server before running the tests. This has 2 problems

1. I have to type my password over and over. Yes I know there are solutions like ssh-agent/ssh-add to not have to type my password though that is now [considered dangerous](https://www.google.com/search?q=ssh-agent+dangerous&oq=ssh-agent+dangerous) since it means any random script can commit as you.
2. If the tests take a long time the authentication may timeout before the tests finish

Ideally I'd like to type `git push origin master` and have git run the tests, then connect to origin. Is there a hook for this case or do I just have to write some other script which runs the tests and then calls git? Which is simple I get it, it just breaks my habit. I like the idea that I can type `git push origin master` and save me from myself by using a hook but I'd like to ask for credentials after passing the tests.

I suppose I could write a wrapper script named `git` that checks specifically for `origin` or `origin master` and runs the tests then calls the real git but in any case,

Is there a pre-push type of hook for git that happens BEFORE git asks for credentials?

Comment: That is, you want a long-running script that any not authenticated hacker can run 1000 times in parallel and bring your server down, right?

Comment: Why not running your unittests with a build tool like *gradle*  or *maven* and have them pushing to git after tests run successfully?

Comment: @phd, I'm not sure how a hacker runs the scripts. pre-hook scripts run locally *before* I push to the server. That's the problem right now. git first makes a connection to the server, then runs the tests locally, if the tests fail it closes the connection. If the tests succeed it actually does the push. Why it does it in that order I'm not sure but it seems like since the tests are running locally it should do that first, then open a connection if and only if the tests succeed.

Comment: Than it's a wrong design. If we know know the script must be fast to avoid login timeout you should move long-running tests out of your `pre-push` hook. Or use `ssh-agent`, it's really useful thing despite some concocted insecurity.